# How do I create a custom validation message on a model passed into a controller c# web api

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, validation, asp.net-web-api

How do I create a custom validation message on a model passed into a controller action method of a c# web API?

Here is the model:

```
[DataContract]
public class TestDto //: IValidatableObject
{
    [DataMember]
    [LongValidation("Its not a long!")]
    public long? ID { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string Description { get; set; }

    public string DescriptionHidden { get; set; }
}
```

Here is my controller class:

```
public class ValuesController : ApiController
{
    // GET api/values
    public IEnumerable<string> Get()
    {
        return new string[] { "value1", "value2" };
    }

    // GET api/values/5
    public string Get(int id)
    {
        return "value";
    }

    // POST api/values
    public string Post([FromBody]TestDto testDto)
    {
        //todo: should a post return any data?
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
            return "success!";
        else
        {
            var ret = string.Empty;
            foreach (var modelState in ModelState)
            {
                ModelErrorCollection errorCollection = modelState.Value.Errors;
                var errors = string.Empty;
                foreach (var error in errorCollection)
                {
                    errors = errors + "exception message: " + error.Exception.Message + ", errorMessage: " + error.ErrorMessage;
                }
                ret = ret + "Error: " + modelState.Key + ", " + modelState.Value.Value + ", errors: " + errors;
            }
            return ret;
        }
    }

    // PUT api/values/5
    public void Put(int id, [FromBody]string value)
    {
    }

    // DELETE api/values/5
    public void Delete(int id)
    {
    }
}
```

If I post this object into the Post action:

```
{
"ID" : "1aaa","Description": "sample string 2",
}
```

In my LongValidation's valid method, I get the default value for a long not : "1aaa", so I cannot perform the correct validation in the validator.

Here is the code for the Long Validator:

```
public class LongValidationAttribute : ValidationAttribute
{
    public LongValidationAttribute(string errorMessage) : base(errorMessage)
    {
    }

    public override string FormatErrorMessage(string name)
    {
        return base.FormatErrorMessage(name);
    }

    protected override ValidationResult IsValid(object value, ValidationContext validationContext)
    {
        long ret;
        bool success = long.TryParse(value.ToString(), out ret);
        //return base.IsValid(value, validationContext);
        if (success == false)
            return new ValidationResult(this.ErrorMessage);
        else
        {
            return ValidationResult.Success;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`1aaa` is not a `long` value, but a `string` value. So when you submit the data to the endpoint, the default model binder will not be able to map this string value to your `long?` property.

If you absolutely want to get this string value mapped to your clas property and get validated, you need to change your property from `long?` to `string` type. But ofcourse now, you need to convert it to long in other parts of your code !

I suggest simply use the appropriate numeric type if you are expecting numeric value in normal use case. In your code you can check whether it is `null` or not and use it as needed.

Answer (score 1):

See this post: https://blog.markvincze.com/how-to-validate-action-parameters-with-dataannotation-attributes/

Basically you need to hook into the MVC pipeline with a custom filter attribute:

```
public class ValidateActionParametersAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute  
{
    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext context)
    {
        var descriptor = context.ActionDescriptor as ControllerActionDescriptor;

        if (descriptor != null)
        {
            var parameters = descriptor.MethodInfo.GetParameters();

            foreach (var parameter in parameters)
            {
                var argument = context.ActionArguments[parameter.Name];

                EvaluateValidationAttributes(parameter, argument, context.ModelState);
            }
        }

        base.OnActionExecuting(context);
    }

    private void EvaluateValidationAttributes(ParameterInfo parameter, object argument, ModelStateDictionary modelState)
    {
        var validationAttributes = parameter.CustomAttributes;

        foreach (var attributeData in validationAttributes)
        {
            var attributeInstance = CustomAttributeExtensions.GetCustomAttribute(parameter, attributeData.AttributeType);

            var validationAttribute = attributeInstance as ValidationAttribute;

            if (validationAttribute != null)
            {
                var isValid = validationAttribute.IsValid(argument);
                if (!isValid)
                {
                    modelState.AddModelError(parameter.Name, validationAttribute.FormatErrorMessage(parameter.Name));
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for show-casing the proper way to do things in the given context. The code snippet given works for asp.net core. I have refactored the code in my answer below to help people struggling to achieve the same functionality in mvc4+. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Based on Kevin's excellent answer I have created the following class to achieve the desired effect under MVC4 / MVC5:

```
public sealed class ValidateActionParametersAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext context)
    {
        var descriptor = context.ActionDescriptor;
        if (descriptor != null)
        {
            var modelState = context.Controller.ViewData.ModelState;
            foreach (var parameterDescriptor in descriptor.GetParameters())
            {
                EvaluateValidationAttributes(
                    suppliedValue: context.ActionParameters[parameterDescriptor.ParameterName],
                    modelState: modelState,
                    parameterDescriptor: parameterDescriptor
                );
            }
        }

        base.OnActionExecuting(context);
    }

    static private void EvaluateValidationAttributes(ParameterDescriptor parameterDescriptor, object suppliedValue, ModelStateDictionary modelState)
    {
        var parameterName = parameterDescriptor.ParameterName;
        parameterDescriptor
            .GetCustomAttributes(inherit: true)
            .OfType<ValidationAttribute>()
            .Where(x => !x.IsValid(suppliedValue))
            .ForEach(x => modelState.AddModelError(parameterName, x.FormatErrorMessage(parameterName)));
    }
}
```

Note: The .ForEach method used above is a simple extension method which you can write on your own.